# Unable to get list items to line up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap on a project. I have regular  anchors styled as buttons, alongside form submit buttons in an unordered list.

However, for some reason, the submit button seems to off by a pixel or two.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Bk97z/1/ for an example of what I am referring to. Note how the middle button is lower than the other two.

I couldn't see anything out of the ordinary when inspecting in firebug. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the framework?

Comment: I suspect it's just down to a difference the way the browser renders an actual button vs a link styled as a button. It doesn't have the same border, but that doesn't account for the offset — I can't see any reason for it to be lower either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead, and add `vertical-align: top`.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Bk97z/5/

```
.view-actions li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```